# SQL Insert Table with Select

Tags: sql, database, oracle

How do i insert into a table using a select statement.
The first_name, last_name, and id_no are from the staff table, but i want to insert the value 1 into the department table as well, but it is not from the staff table.

```
INSERT INTO department ('1',  id_no, first_name, last_name)
SELECT FROM staff
WHERE id_no = 1;
```

I am using SQL developer in oracle

Comment: Can you show the structure of department table? Or just the names of the fields, you want insert into.

Answer (score 3):

If "department" has those four columns in that order, you are pretty close.

```
INSERT INTO department (foo,  id_no, first_name, last_name)
SELECT 1, staff_id, staff_first_name, staff_last_name
FROM staff
WHERE id_no = 1;
```

(obviously change the column names appropriately in the `SELECT`)
Of course, this will insert only one row, assuming that `id_no` is unique.

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO department(OTHER_COLUMN,id_no, first_name, last_name) 
SELECT '1',  id_no, first_name, last_name FROM staff WHERE id_no = 1
```

replace OTHER_COLUMN with the name of the column

Answer (score 1):

That's invalid SQL.  Assuming that `staff` has the same field names as `department`

```
INSERT INTO department(id_no, first_name, last_name)
SELECT id_no, first_name, last_name
FROM staff
WHERE id_no = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

To `INSERT INTO` table values from `SELECT` you need to write something like:

```
INSERT INTO department (dep_field1, dep_field2, dep_field3)
SELECT '1', staff_field1, staff_field2
FROM staff
WHERE condition;
```

In `department (...)` part you need name fields from `department` table, you want to insert into.

In `SELECT` you need to name fields from `staff` table, you want to select from.

Answer (score 0):

I Think you would find an answer to your problem here: [INSERT Statement](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/insert.php)

if the SQL you have added to the post is what you tried - it's not working because it says `FROMM` - double M.  Change it to `FROM` and it might work...